# Is a live internet connection required for push notification?

Tags: android, tcp, push-notification

This maybe a silly question, but I need confirmation and I have no one else to ask.

I am trying to understand the implications of implementing my own push notification for android mobile devices. This requires a continuous TCP connection to a server, though most of the time it will be idle.

My assumption is that, even when idle, for the server to be able to push data to the client through the TCP connection, an active internet connection will always be required, and if the connection is disrupted (i.e. the user switches the connection off) this push will no longer be possible.

Is this assumption correct ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say yes, it's correct indeed. How would you communicate without a live internet connection?

Afaik, Android C2DM handles this by queueing up the push requests when the user does not have a live net connection and sending them down to the user when the connection gets back up. You could implement a similar behavior in your solution's server side.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is **YES**

To understand the best way then any-other about C2DM, You just should go through this **[Google Project C2DM](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/)**

They have provided complete documentation required to Understand the work and mechanism of C2DM and provided completed Examples too.

I have one another favourite tutorial for the same is : **[Vogella's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html)**

You just need to give a good time to read this thing and implement..

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. C2DM maintains a open socket (with Market or Gmail app), which it uses to identify your device.
And ofcourse, you will need Wifi or a cellular network to receive the push notifications.